# How do I prevent Electron from launching an additional instance in a new browser window?

Tags: reactjs, electron

`npm start` is launching my React/Electron application in two different windows: One window is a native desktop window, and the other window is a Chrome browser window.  I only want one instance of the application launch in a native desktop window.

Answer (score -1):

Add the setting `BROWSER=none` to [the .env file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) of the React application.